# Replace a specific line+column of one file with line+column of another in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I have the following files:

file0.c:

```
int b=NULL;
int a=NULL;
```

file1.c:

```
int b;
int a=NULL;
```

file2.c:

```
int b=NULL;
int a;
```

I am looking to merge the files file1 and file2 to generate the following result.c:

```
int b;
int a;
```

I can use : `diff input0 input1` and `diff input0 input2` to get the line+column combinations, however I don't know what to do next in order to achieve the above results.

Comment: The above is just an example, what I am after is to merge two files which have have differences into a single file relative to a common ancestor

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not clear what exactly your file pattern constraints are, I will just post a solution that will work for your example:

```
cat file[012].c | grep -v "=NULL" | sort | uniq > result.c
```

Maybe this is enough to get you started with your own solution. Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi, I am just looking to owerwrite lines from one file to another in a way that the file being owerwrite is preserved and only specefic lines are changed.